# How to check if specific directory exists under a directory? 

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check if a directory `Test` exists under the path `C:\mypath\is\here`?

```
String[] getAllSubDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, Match, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (String subDir in getAllSubDirs)
{
    if (!subDir.Contains("test"))
    {
        ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(subDir);
        list.SubItems.Add("N/A");
        listView.Items.Add(list);
        listView.EnsureVisible(list.Index);
    }
}
```

I want to print out those directories that do not have a  folder named `Test` present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
!subDir.Contains("test")
```

do

```
!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(subDir, "Test"))
```

Comment: not sure it work, i want get feedback if the folder "test" is in one of the folders that i scan trough with the foreach

Comment: Which folder should not contain the Test folder? The "directory" folder or its subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(subDir, "test"))
```

or if you just know the full path:

```
Directory.Exists("C:\mypath\is\here\test")
```

Comment: dont know the path, but going through a dir, and if i find test in one of the subdirs.it shal repport